# Can we get the Sender email ID programmatically?

Tags: android, email, gmail, jakarta-mail, yahoo-mail

I have an Query like :

**If I'll configure an email account in my app than `Is` it possible:**

**1. Can I get the sender email address by programmatic-ally ?**

**2. Through code can I stop the synchronization for email account ?**

Is this possible or not, all suggestion welcome ?

Comment: What does "configure an email account in my app" mean?

Comment: Like  : I'll pass email_id, password, port _no, incoming_mail_server, outgoing_mail_server, SSl type and configure mail... @CommonsWare

Comment: can u give any real time example to understand this question pls

Comment: like : k9-mail @harikrishnan

Comment: real time example : k-9 mail @CommonsWare

Comment: I understood for getting sender mail, for this purpose of this app...

Comment: why i am asking means, suppose, we will create a app page for compose mail like that, then, when we send mail using our app via means, when we click send button, we will get the to mail ids..and from,inbox messages also..

Comment: actually the problem is, In my application i am getting all incoming mails but instead of getting mails, i want to block all incoming mails and auto reply to those incoming mails with custom message like "i am on vacation, will read your message after getting back to home".

Comment: so i want the incoming mail id to send message back automatically.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38886/discussion-between-a-m-and-harikrishnan)

Comment: just see this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925542/how-to-get-gmail-mails-programmatically-in-android    will talk tom..\