# Is there any Android app which will call a mobile number after receiving an email?

Tags: android, mobile

after receiving the call by other end,he will hear some voice which will be sent via email. Mobile number and the text will be in the email.

Answer (score 0):

The question and the description of the question are a litte confused, but if you want to call a mobile phone: [How to make a phone call programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816683/how-to-make-a-phone-call-programmatically)
and if you want to receive emails in your application, you can use this:
[How to get gmail mails programmatically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925542/how-to-get-gmail-mails-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: https://smsgateway.me/ Something like it but instead of SMS I want to make calls from my android mobile.